# Use template literal types to define possible properties on typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use template literals to define an object with certain keys based on a provided string. The idea is to take a string as type argument and type the returned object to contain certain keys of certain types. However, typescript doesn't allow me to define more than one property this way. Seems that I have to create an union of all the possibilities, but that is too broad and not what I want.

Here is a non working example of what I want to achieve:

```
type LoadingStates<Prefix extends string> = {
    [key in `${Prefix}Pending`]: boolean;
    [key in `${Prefix}Error`]: string | null
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an intersection between the two mapped types. The effect will be exactly what you are looking for:

```
type LoadingStates<Prefix extends string> = {
    [key in `${Prefix}Pending`]: boolean;
} & {
    [key in `${Prefix}Error`]: string | null
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gQwCYEsB2BzAysBwIDOAPAAoBOEAZigB5QQ35pIFQHBnoYB8UAvFADeAWABQUCVADaAawggo6KAAMAJIPJVaAXxIRmXZQF0AXFABGcOABsICNAG4x2qADIhYydLkKlajRTUNNoAomRkcGTGZuycmFAAPlBoAK7W1s5QYmK2wFA0ZvDIXDh4hEQARAAaFbwCIuJQVWERZGap6QA0nk16BphmlAjWBBDOQA)

You could also use the predefined type `Record` instead of custom mapped types:

```
type LoadingStates<Prefix extends string> = Record<`${Prefix}Pending`, boolean> & Record<`${Prefix}Error`, string | null>
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning it's possible to do just `type LoadingStates<Prefix extends string> = Record<\`${Prefix}Pending\`, boolean> & Record<\`${Prefix}Error\`, string | null>`

Comment: @BorisTB Yup. I added the option. Thanks.

Comment: I was having an haircut and this idea crossed my mind. Glad to see it makes sense! Thanks